# xml xsl xpath transformation using wildcard on element

Tags: xslt, xpath, conditional-statements

I have a whack of unfriendly and half-baked xml files that resemble the following:

```
<root>
<child0><name0>Bob Dylan</name0></child0>
<child1><name1>Daft Punk</name1></child1>
<child2><name2>Nine Inch Nails</name2></child2>
</root>
```

and i wish to transform each file into the following:

```
<root><children>
<child><name>Bob Dylan</name></child>
<child><name>Daft Punk</name></child>
<child><name>Nine Inch Nails</name></child> 
</children>
</root>
```

each file does not have a deterministic number of children. some have only `<child0>` while others have `<child0> ... <child10>`. the elements within children are also not determined, eg. name[0], etc.

so i would like to walk through each child (perhaps with a wildcard or ends-with, or ??) to match the numeral that is always terminating the child and childs's child element.

this doesnt work but something along the lines of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="child*" >
     <child>
     <name><xsl:value-of select="name[index]"></name>
     </child>
</xsl:for-each>
```

ive seen plenty of examples of select,if and match conditions that deal with selecting the content within a element (or an element by way of position or index)...
because thats the way it should be done.

but i have valid yet half-baked xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a straightforward, push-oriented solution that accomplishes what you want. Note that it will work using either XSLT/XPath 1.0 or 2.0.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
      <children>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </children>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'child')]">
    <child>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </child>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'name')]">
     <name>
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </name>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied to the original XML:**

```
<root>
  <child0>
    <name0>Bob Dylan</name0>
  </child0>
  <child1>
    <name1>Daft Punk</name1>
  </child1>
  <child2>
    <name2>Nine Inch Nails</name2>
  </child2>
</root>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<root>
  <children>
    <child>
      <name>Bob Dylan</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <name>Daft Punk</name>
    </child>
    <child>
      <name>Nine Inch Nails</name>
    </child>
  </children>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to use a regex on the name() value:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[matches(name(),'^child\d$')]">
...
```

Comment: thanks. that suggest that most or all conditional will work on that name value. great.
also updated the original with the <name0>