# Get all tags with a specific name independent of element-level

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I'm creating html with PHP (simpleXML), a XML-document and XSL.

Is there a way to replace all elements with a specific name (ie. ) with a html-tag (ie. ). I guess the answer is 'yes", but how do I do it?

With my code, the keyword-element must be the top child of the root-element for it to work.

The following don't work:

XML:

```
<document>
<chapter>This is the first chapter</chapter>
<text>This is a text, with a <keyword>keyword</keyword></text>
</document>
```

XSL:

```
    <xsl:template match="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'keyword')]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <b>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </b>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

The `<keyword>`-element can exist on all kinds of levels in the document, lets say even in the title. How can I then select it from the XSL? I guess there is something to do with the 'match'-attribute. I tried match="*/keyword" without any luck.

This code works when the `<keyword>`-element is the top child of the root, but won't work inside for example the `<text>`-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your input example to:

```
<document>
    <title>This is the <keyword>first</keyword> title</title>
    <chapter>This is the <keyword>second</keyword> chapter</chapter>
    <text>This is a text, with a <keyword>third</keyword> keyword in it.</text>
</document>
```

Using the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Identity Transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- exception -->
<xsl:template match="keyword">
    <b><xsl:apply-templates/></b>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
    <title>This is the <b>first</b> title</title>
    <chapter>This is the <b>second</b> chapter</chapter>
    <text>This is a text, with a <b>third</b> keyword in it.</text>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not total sure what you are trying to do, but the following  query:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="//keyword/text()"/>
```

will select all `<keyword>` element's content regardless of their position in tree. This because I'm using the `//` in front of

Comment: I have updated my question a little. Yes, I'm trying to select all <keyword>-elements, and I want to replace them with <b> tags.

Comment: user3016153 gave the perfect answer. nothing more to say :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663868/xml-xsl-xpath-transformation-using-wildcard-on-element).

Basically, the `*/keyword` is looking for a string that has "/keyword" in it, and not the actual node.

If you try

```
    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'keyword')]">
```

You should be in good shape.

Comment: Seems like this was something I was looking for. Thanks! Still it won't work on any other than top child elements of the root. I have updated my question.

Comment: Have you tried the solution below - replace the * with //?  I haven't set any of this up to test, so im throwing out ideas.

Comment: Seems like it does that same as yours. It seems to work on elements that are child of root-element, but somehow not on the others. Do I have to do a nesting in XSL in the same structure as the XML-document? If so, it would be a mess to find all <keyword>-elements. I'm pretty new to XML, so I'm throwing out some questions.

Comment: The XML validates. Try using something like http://www.xpathtester.com/ to try your xpath out.  Tools like this make it easier to iterate.

Comment: You could also try ends-with() instead