# How to structure XSL to create HTML from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML document for a book. Each XML-document is one chapter, that is structured in the following way:

```
<doc>
<chapter title="This is the first chapter">
<section>This is a section of information</section>
<paragraph title="This is the first paragraph">This is the text of the first paragraph</paragraph>
<section><paragraph title="This is the second paragraph">This paragraph is inside a secion</paragraph></section>
</chapter>
</doc>
```

I have a PHP to generate HTML from XSL, but my problem is to structure the XSL in a good way. As you see, paragraphs isn't necessarily the first child of a chapter. And a section can contain a paragraph, but doesn't have to.

How can I easily structure this in XSL? Do I have to nest a bunch of foreach tags? I tried something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc/chapter">
                    <h1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@title"/>
                    </h1>

                <xsl:for-each select="current()/paragraph">
                        <h3>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()/@title" />
                        </h3>

                            <p><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></p>
        </xsl:for-each>

                <xsl:for-each select="current()/section">
                        <h2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()/@title" />
                        </h2>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current()/paragraph">
                            <h3>
                                <xsl:value-of select="current()/@title" />
                            </h3>

                                <p><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></p>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that this will be very advanced and a lot of duplicate foreach'es nested in each other. Is there an easier and better approach for this. If so, how?

Comment: Have you looked at using XSL Template?

Comment: Have read a little about it, just didn't know how to approach it. But got a good answer here now, so XSL Template is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use template matching here, which is really what XSLT is all about, and excels at. If you want to transform a **paragraph** element the same way, regardless of where it exists in the document, you first create a template describing how to transform it

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
   <h3>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()/@title"/>
   </h3>
   <p>
     <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, instead of doing an **xsl:for-each**, you can replace it with **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph" />
```

(Note, there is no need to use "current()" here, as it is assumed the xpath expression is relative to the current context node anyway).

But this is still not ideal, as it is assuming you are expecting a **paragraph** at this point, when maybe there are other elements. Better still is when you do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates />
```

This will process all the current child nodes of the current element, and look for templates that match. This will work well if you do have templates for all elements you are wanting to transform.

It is also worth mentioning about XSLT's built-in templates. These will be used to match nodes for which there are no explicit matching templates in your XSLT. These built in templates will output text nodes where they find them, otherwise they will continue processing by looking for templates that match the children of the current node.

You can take advantage of these built-in templates to simplify your XSLT. For example, here is one way of writing it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="chapter">
         <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
         </h1>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="paragraph">
      <h3>
         <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
      </h3>
      <p>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </p>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice how there is no template matching **doc** or **section**, but the built-in templates will process, allowing execution to eventually pass to the explicit templates.

EDIT: If you did want to do more changes, just add more changes as required. For example, if you had **Section** elements with **title** attributes, just add the following template:

```
   <xsl:template match="section[@title]">
      <h2>
         <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
      </h2>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>
```

This template will match **section** elements, but only ones with **title** attributes present.

Comment: This looks good, but as you may see in my question sections may also have headings. I can't see how your example adds <h3>-tags?

Comment: My answer was primarily to demonstrate the principal, and I left the rest as an exercise for the reader (especially because there is no mention of <h3> tags in your question.... However, I have amended my question with more details, which I hope may help!

Comment: My bad. Just a typo in the code in my question (wrote h2 instead of h3 on paragraph). Updated now so question and answer fits. Your answers helps a lot!

Comment: @janlindso: In [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548172/get-all-tags-with-a-specific-name-independent-of-element-level) you have shown that your structural elements may contain additional markup, This is why, IMHO, you should start your stylesheet with an [identity transform template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) as the default (as I suggested there). Using the built-in default templates as shown here will remove the additional markup and output plain text only.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered switching to the [docbook](http://www.docbook.org/) format? The advantage of adopting a standard is that you get to leverage the pre-existing stylesheets for supporting various output formats.

To illustrate the point here is a sample document:

```
<book>
  <title>An Example Book</title>
  <chapter>
    <title>This is the first chapter</title>
    <section>
      <title>This is the first section</title>
      <para>Paragraph one</para>
      <para>Paragraph two</para>
    </section>
    <section>
      <title>This is the second section</title>
      <para>Paragraph one</para>
      <para>Paragraph two</para>
    </section>
  </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: Would love to, thanks for the tip! Unfortunately several people are involved in this project, with, unfortunately, an already decided standard.

Comment: @janlindso That is a pity... Docbook is pretty much the accepted standard for XML publishing now. You might also take a look at asciidoc (and asciidoctor) which can be used to generate docbook XML from lightweight markup. Very powerful stuff.